# How do I stack rows in a Pandas data frame to get one “long row”, preserving column types?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a follow up to [How do I stack rows in a Pandas data frame to get one "long row"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900981/how-do-i-stack-rows-in-a-pandas-data-frame-to-get-one-long-row)

The answers there work but dropping the index here loses column types (they all become *object*):

```
df.stack().reset_index(drop=True).T
```

I need to preserve column types, and preferably rename columns with prefixes indicating the original row, for example:

`row_0_column_A, row_0_column_B, ... , row_5_column_A, row_5_column_B ...`

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( [ {'stringy': 'A', 'numerical': 2 }, { 'stringy': 'B', 'numer
ical': 3 } ] )

   numerical stringy
0          2       A
1          3       B
```

Desired output:

```
   row_0_numerical row_0_stringy row_1_numerical row_1_stringy
0                2             A               3             B
```

How to?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and output to demonstrate exactly what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `pivot` your table:

```
# create a unique id for all rows and pivot the table
df['id'] = 0    
df1 = df.reset_index().pivot(index = 'id', columns = 'index')

# collapse multi index columns to single index
df1.columns = ['_'.join(['row'] + [str(c) for c in col][::-1]) for col in df1.columns.values]

df1
#      row_0_numerical  row_1_numerical row_0_stringy   row_1_stringy
# id                
#  0                 2                3             A               B
```